# How do you rig a character that has multiple individual meshes?

Tags: rigging

I have a creature with multiple hand placed scales all over it's back side which are all separate meshes. How do you rig them to the character itself without causing clipping?

Do I have to manually weight paint every single one of them? They are about 200 of them. Or do I add individual bones to each scale?

Does anyone know an effective way of rigging something like this?

Comment: is each scale supposed to move independently? what did the Parent > With Automatic Weight give? Perhaps make a screenshot so that we can understand better your topology and armature...

Comment: For curiosity sake, can you add a pic of said creature?